# VBA If with two criteria in two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I need to look at two cells (C and F) on a each row, and if the value for C to ends with 30 and the value for F is greater than Zero, copy and paste the row to another sheet.  I've managed to get the copy and paste to work using 1 criteria, but I cannot figure out how to get both criteria to work together.

```
Sub compile1()
    Dim x As String

Set rSearch = Sheets("Application").Range("C:C")


For Each cell In rSearch
x = cell.Value
       If Right(cell, 2) = "30" And cell.Offset(, 3) > 0 Then

        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Application").Select
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You've said the answer in your question AND, but I'd use something lke your commented line, `If Right(x, 2) = "30" And x.offset(0,3).value> 0 Then`

Comment: Your range is wrong, you only need C in there, the offset moves to F and use X rather than cell again for the value comparison ="30"

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thank you.  Fixed and now working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Sub CP()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = Sheets("Application").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To n
    With Sheets("Application")
        If Right(Cells(i, 3), 2) = 30 And Cells(i, 6).Value > 0 Then
            .Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 3)
            .Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 6)
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

I have used column 3 to count the number of rows and hence assumed this is the main column

Comment: The data starts in Col A and ends Col L, I need the entire row copied if the criteria is met, not just the two cells.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the `Next` statement in your second for `each loop`.
The two criterias can be taken together with this line:

```
If y > 0 And Right(x, 2) = "30" Then
```

so the whole code would be...

```
Sub compile1()
Dim x As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim rSearch As Range
Dim rSearch1 As Range
Dim cell As Range, cell1 As Range
Dim matchRow As Integer

Set rSearch = Sheets("Application").Range("C:c")
Set rSearch1 = Sheets("Application").Range("F:F")

For Each cell In rSearch
    x = cell.Value
    For Each cell1 In rSearch1
    y = cell1.Value
        If y > 0 And Right(x, 2) = "30" Then
            matchRow = cell.Row
            Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
            Selection.Copy

            Sheets("sheet2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Application").Select
        End If
    Next cell1
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To speed things up I'd suggest the following:

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
Dim x As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim WS1 As Worksheet

Set WS1 = ActiveSheet
y = 1
Do Until y > WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row, Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    x = Trim(Cells(y, 3).Value)
    If Right(x, 2) = "30" And (IsNumeric(Cells(y, 6).Value) And Cells(y, 6).Value > 0) Then Rows(y & ":" & y).Copy: Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False: Application.CutCopyMode = False
    y = y + 1
Loop

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("A1").Activate
WS1.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: A further performance enhancement would be to use arrays, so `arr1=range(c1:c100).value`,`arr1=range(f1:f100).value`, then loop the arrays

Comment: @Nathan_Sav While arrays are usually a good way of improving performance, I don't think that's the case here (happy to be corrected though)

Comment: array 16ms, range 31ms in my test of 7000 rows :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Well then, that's settled! :)

Comment: I was doing something similar, not a pedantic argument :)

Comment: Hi both, sorry to say this did not work, I've updated the original post with my newer code...

Comment: @J.Zentner are you running 97-2003 version of excel?

Comment: @Jeremy, I am running 2010 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code once - this is way too simpler and optimized processing than loops (slower)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheets("Application").AutoFilterMode = False

Dim lastrow, lastcol As Integer
lastrow = Range("F500000").End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Sheets("Application").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column + 1

Sheets("Application").Cells(1, lastcol).Value = "helper"
Sheets("Application").Range(Sheets("Application").Cells(1, lastcol),Sheets("Application").Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).FormulaR1C1 = "=Right(RC[-1],2)"

Sheets("Application").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).AutoFilter Field:=lastcol, Criteria1:="30"
Sheets("Application").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"

Sheets("Application").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A2")

Columns(lastcol).Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: If I replace <code>x = cell.Value
    If Right(x,2)="30"Then
ForEach cell1 In rSearch1y = cell1.Value
    If y >0Then</code> with <Code>If Right(cell, 2) = "30" And cell.Offset(, 3) > 0 Then</code> then it correctly omits  rows where the value in col F is negative, however it is pulling through values where the last two digits in Col F happen to be 30. What I need is for only Col C's last two digits to be 30, and Col to be greater than 0.

Comment: Did you run my code, this is doing exactly what you you need.

Comment: All it did was add a filter in Col C with nothing selected.

Comment: change sheet2 to sheets(_destinationsheet)) to reflect changes
in this line -
Sheets("Application").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=**Sheet2**.Range("A2")

Comment: And, also, if possible, give your sheet to me, it will not take minutes for me to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub compile1()
Dim Cel As Range, Rng As Range

Set rSearch = Sheets("Application").Columns("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

For Each Cel In rSearch
   If Right(Trim(Cel.Value), 2) = "30" And (Cel.Offset(, 3).Value > 0) Then
        Cel.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You should avoid `.Select` instructions at all costs since it is slower and with a higher probability of occurring errors. You should also get your last row with information since looping all the rows until the end does not like very efficient...

Comment: @Jeremy, do you have any other suggestions on how I can make it quicker?  I've managed to get the entire code to work and paste when I need where I need it, but you are both right, it takes and age to run.

Comment: @J.Zentner something like my edit? if you don't like it you can roll it back

Comment: @Jeremy, get a 424: Object required error on the new If Right...line

Comment: @Jeremy, removed the isNumeric, but now get an 438: Object doesnt support this property or Method on ln 9: sheets...

You've also created Rng As Range but it is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire code. It works but takes ages to run.  Any help to speed it up would be appreciated.

```
Sub Master()
Call compile1
Call compile2
End Sub
Sub compile1()
For Each cell In Sheets("Application").Range("C:C")
    If Right(cell.Value, 2) = "10" Then
        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Routine w credits").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Application").Select
    End If
Next

For Each cell In Sheets("Application").Range("C:C")
    If Right(cell.Value, 2) = "20" Then
        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Reactive w credits").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Application").Select
    End If
Next

End Sub

Sub compile2()

Set rSearch = Sheets("Application").Range("C:C")

For Each cell In rSearch

   If Right(cell, 2) = "20" And cell.Offset(, 3) > 0 Then

        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Reactive wo credits").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Application").Select
    End If

Next

For Each cell In rSearch

   If Right(cell, 2) = "10" And cell.Offset(, 3) > 0 Then

        matchRow = cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Routine wo credits").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Application").Select
    End If

Next
End Sub
```